# meanings of Android GC Log message

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-logcat

First I'd like to paste some GC log messages here for Honeycomb .

```
03-08 01:31:54.354: D/dalvikvm(258): GC_CONCURRENT freed 196K, 5% free 7078K/7431K, paused 3ms+3ms
03-08 01:31:54.494: D/dalvikvm(258): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 5% free 7073K/7431K, paused 75ms
03-08 01:31:54.494: I/dalvikvm-heap(258): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.391MB for 411152-byte allocation
```

I have 4 questions here.

1. I have watch the video "[Android Memory Management](http://youtu.be/_CruQY55HOk)" in Google i/o 2011,but I am still not clear about 5% free 7078K/7431K. It means we use 7078K in 7431K heap size, but what does 7431K mean here? Because I notice that 7431K will be up to a large number. Is there any policy for this number?If it means total heap size,it should be 16M or 32M or something like that.But here obviously not..
2. Honeycomb also has message like `Grow heap (frag case) to 7.391MB for 411152-byte allocation`, which Gingerbread does not have .What does it mean?
3. GC log messages in Honeycomb and later does not show external memory information like "external xxxK/xxxK",why?
4. I also notice that in ICS and later version,GC log message also has a total time like `GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 190K, 13% free 5409K/6164K, paused 67ms, total 71ms`,but here alloc gc's total time is larger than paused time,and sometimes you will notice that total time would be much larger than paused time.Why?

Answer (score 0):

On point 3 (about external memory information), it could be because the bitmaps are part of Dalvik memory than the external memory now, and hence there is little relevance of external memory to Garbage Collector.